# Is every closed set (in R) countable?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove something and was wondering if one can assume that any closed set in the real numbers is countable. Im not finding any info so Im wondering if that statement is too vague.

Comment: What is true is that any closed set of reals is either countable or has the same size as the reals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, one cannot assume that any closed set is countable. For example, consider [0,1]. This set is closed but it has uncountably many numbers.

Comment: I know that the interval [0,1] is uncountable but is there no difference between a set and an interval? Or do you mean the set of numbers in the interval [0,1]?

Comment: An interval is a particular case of a set.

Comment: @TatianaFrank In the usual sense an interval is a set, i.e. $[0,1]$ is exactly the same as $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 0 \text{ and } x \leq 1 \}$.

Comment: An interval is just a special kind of set. We can even think of all of R as being a set. So you are correct that I mean the set of numbers in the interval [0,1].

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I realize now my real question was about the definition of a set :)

Comment: No worries. If this answer is correct, can you please mark it as so?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in any topology of $\mathbb{R}$ there are a uncountable closed sets: take $\mathbb{R}$